# Ionic Navigation Controller - check if page has been loaded already

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, ionic-framework

Ok..I notice that each time I push a new page in the navigation controller, the page is rendered the page state is always the default.
Lets say a user goes to a page, modifies some data, later comes back to the page and his changes are gone.
Is there any way I can restore the page, in case he has already been there?
Here is my idea for now, I was wondering if there was a better approach?

```
            //Check if page was not visited already
            console.log('Check if page was not already loaded.')
            let restoredFromHistory = false;
            this.navCtrl.getViews().forEach( view => { 
                if(view.name == 'CartPage'){
                    console.log('Page was found in the history.')
                    this.navCtrl.push(view);
                    restoredFromHistory = true;
                }
            })

            if(!restoredFromHistory){
                console.log('Page was not found in the history. Pushing a brand new.')
                this.navCtrl.push(CartPage)
            }
```

Comment: You could write the history to a service and later restore it from there `historyService.set(key, data)` and `historyService.get(key)`

Comment: You could use a service as mentioned by @Delpes and on entering the page you could call a lifecycle event at the first place to get the data from the service. so that only after populating the data the page is loaded fully

Comment: Ok..I wrote a servie to get and set the pages, however everytime I try to restore a page from the history I get the error: Inserted view was already destroyed. I am setting the view on ionViewWillLeave. Any idea how to restore a view that has been destroyed?